# MYSQL VIEW over multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, view

I'm trying to figure out if I can create a view over 3 dissimilar files.

The resulting view needs to look something like: 
entryID int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Internal Entry ID',
entryYear int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entry Year',
entrytype varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'free form',
sortstring longtext NOT NULL COMMENT 'Sorting string',

The entryID and entryYear will be from the 3 tables. The entrytype field gets set to HOLDER/GUEST/BLACKLIST based up on which table the data is from.

The "HOLDER" table:
entryID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Internal Entry ID',
entryYear int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entry Year',
LastName varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Last Name',
FirstName varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'First Name',

The guest table:
entryID bigint(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID of holder form',
LastName varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Guest Last Name',
FirstName varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Guest First Name',

The Blacklist table:
blackID bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Internal Guest ID',
LastName varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Guest Last Name',
FirstName varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Guest First Name',

When all said an done, I would have a view like this:
1 2021 HOLDER  'Doe Jane'
1 2021 GUEST   'Doe John'
2 2021 GUEST   'Doe Bertha'
1 2021 BLACKLIST 'Politician Any'
2 2021 HOLDER  'Mouse Mickey'
3 2021 GUEST   'Mouse Minnie'

Right now, this is being done with a work table that has be to updated whenever data changes. Having to recreate the work table frequently causes other processes to slow down and is can be just a pain.

Comment: What is the problem? the syntax for `CREATE VIEW` does not seem to be very complex....

Comment: I have no clue how to start this one. It's a union of sorts, but not sure beyond that.

Comment: The work table that you are talking about, is it re-created when it is updated, or are only new records added? If it is re-created, then please share the SQL that takes care of that. (use [edit] to add that info to your question)

Comment: The work file is updated via PHP code. The PHP routine reads each of the three files, in sequence, and puts HOLDER, GUEST, BLACKLIST in the entrytype field as it writes each record type to the work file.

Comment: On the larger systems I often work with, the merge can be down with a logical-join file in it's native DB handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a query which get the result that needs to be in the "work table". For now let's pretend it is `SELECT * FROM holder;`, but it can be more complex using UNION's, LEFT JOIN's, RIG... anything, as long as it is a valid SQL statement.

Now you can pre-pend `CREATE VIEW myAwesomNewView AS` to your SQL statement.

This will look like:

```
CREATE VIEW myAwesomNewView AS
SELECT * FROM holder;
```

After this you will be able to do `SELECT * FROM myAwesomNewView`. This should produce the same result (in this example) as: `SELECT * FROM holder;`

Your biggest problem seems to be in creating the query which produces the contents that need to be in the "work table".

May I wish you much succes on debugging the PHP code that is used to fill the "work table", while converting that into a single SQL statement.

It might be wise to read [Restrictions on Views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-restrictions.html), before starting the actual work...

Comment: The code builds the work table just fine. The issue is the time to rebuild it when information changes in HOLDER, GUEST, or BLACKLIST tables.  I was hoping a view would make the update from the feeder tables more dynamic so I could eliminate the work table. So far, from that I find, that doesn't look like a possibility.

Comment: @JayBenton - MySQL does not implement "materialized views".  A MySQL `VIEW` is just syntactic sugar around a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

```
( SELECT  blackID AS id,
        entryYear,
        'BLACKLIST' AS type,
        CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS name
    FROM Blacklist
    WHERE ... )  -- if need any filtering
UNION ALL
( SELECT  entryID,
        entryYear,
        'HOLDER' AS type,
        CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS name
    FROM Holder
    WHERE ... )
UNION ALL
( SELECT  entryID,
        entryYear,
        'GUEST' AS type,
        CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS name
    FROM Guest
    WHERE ... )
ORDER BY ...  -- overall ordering, if needed
```

Notes:

- `UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION`, and it is applicable in your case
- I put `BLACKLIST` first because it is the longest.  Any other order might lead to truncation of that column.
- The column names come from the first `SELECT`.  Hence I was careful to give `blackID` the alias `id`.
- Some tables don't seem to have "year".  If that is really the case, use `NULL`.
- This could be wrapped in a `VIEW`.  But I suggest you try it as is until you get the details worked out.